# How to undo Apps2SD

Tags: sd-card, app2sd

I have a G1 phone.  I made a partition to install applications on the SD Card using Apps2SD.  But I don't like it, I'd like to decouple the specific SD Card from being a requirement to using the phone.

How do I undo Apps2SD?  I'd like to have Apps only on the phone now.

Answer (score 3):

Apps2SD may be able to do this, but I haven't looked too closely.  The long way to do it would be to go through Settings->Applications->Manage Applications and then manually move everything back to the phone.

==ADDENDUM==

ApptoSD doesn't give you the nice "Move all to Phone" like it does for move to SD, but it does list everything on the SD card.  There is also a "On SD" tab in the Manage Applications settings so you don't have to go through each and every app.

Comment: clarification -- go through everything in the "On SD" tab and select "Move To Phone"