# Enable/Disable automatic SD card installations in android phone

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sd-card, app2sd

i don't know why, but in recent 3 day, my memory card goes crazy! and sometimes (3 times in a day) notify me : "damaged memory card, do you want to format it?"
and when i format sd card, some applications corrupted and can't run, because it says : "this application not installed in your phone!"
is there a way to disable or disallow android from installing or storing any data related to application installed on phone?
phone Specs:

- model : samsung GT-I9100G
- Build number : Gingerbread.JPKK1
- android version : 2.3.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is a mix of multiple problems. First, your apps becoming "unavailable" is most likely due to Apps2SD being used, and you installed those on your SD card. See:

- [How to undo Apps2SD](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-to-undo-apps2sd)

Second thing is your card itself (hardware, the "thing you put inside your device"). If it goes broke that often, this rises some hardware related questions. Most likely possibilities:

1. Your card is broken
2. Your devices card adapter is broken
3. Something with your card controller is broken

You can check 1. easily in different ways:

A. check whether your card causes problems in other devices
B. check whether other cards cause the same problems with your SGS

If (A but not B) => use a new card (case 1.)
If (B but not A) => have your device checked (for either 2. or 3.). Hopefully you've got some warranty left.

Other useful Q&As on this site which might prove helpful to you include (but are not limited to):

- [Why has my micro SD card suddenly stopped working in my Samsung Galaxy SIII?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27707/why-has-my-micro-sd-card-suddenly-stopped-working-in-my-samsung-galaxy-siii)
- [Micro SD card physically damaged?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7289/micro-sd-card-physically-damaged)
- [how to fix damaged sd card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/how-to-fix-damaged-sd-card?)
- [Fix a damaged microsd card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25278/fix-a-damaged-microsd-card?)

Comment: i don't use app2sd application. About other things you said; i'll check today. Thank you.any relation between this problem and card class [A,B or C] ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Never heard of class A..C -- just numeric values. There's the higher the faster (and as a side effect, often less power hungry).

Comment: Yap,got it. Now number 2; why when i install app in phone storage, i see some data related to that application saved in sd card?! A directory named android.

Comment: That might be app *data* (data the app stores when used). And class 2 is ancient and slow. Even class 4 is quite slow. If you buy a new one, get a higher class (not a must, but a strong recommendation) -- class 6 or higher I'd say. I personally would go below that.

Comment: it's so bad. in galaxy sII 16Gb, you can install applications in 2Gb space, and other 11Gb is for your books or media. i want it, why just 2Gb! it's very low! i had googled it and no response, other users face this problem and no one solve this. forum moderators say that it's good think for stability ,but i don't!